# titan rexster with external cassandra instance

Tags: cassandra, titan, rexster

I have a cassandra cluster (2.1.0) running fine.
After installing titan 5.1, and editing the titan-cassandra.properties to point to cluster  hostname list rather than localhost, i run following -
`titan.sh -c conf/titan-cassandra.properties start` 
It is able to recognize running cassandra instance, starts elastic search, but times out while connecting to rexster.
If i run it with local cassandra, everything runs fine using following ->br>

```
titan.sh start
```

do i need to make any change in rexster properties to point to running cassandra cluster..

 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Titan Server started by `titan.sh` represents a quick way to get started with Titan/Rexster/ES.  It is designed to simplify running all those things with one startup script.  Once you start breaking things apart (e.g. a separate cassandra cluster), you might not want to use `titan.sh` anymore because, it still forks a cassandra process when it starts up.  Presumably, you don't need that anymore, given that you have a separate cassandra cluster.

Given the more advanced nature of your environment, I would simply download Rexster and [configure](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.1/server.html#_downloading_rexster_and_titan_separately) it to connect to your cluster.