# Script to run Rexster as a daemon in linux

Tags: linux, daemon, graph-databases, titan, rexster

I'm setting up Titan graph database for the first time in a production environment on Debian virtual machines, and I am utilising Rexster to provide the interface into Titan. However after googling around I cannot find any scripts to allow rexster to run as a daemon in the background. As per [titan rexster with external cassandra instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707000/titan-rexster-with-external-cassandra-instance/26713039#26713039) I have split off Cassandra, Elasticsearch, and Rexster to start as their own processes. Cassandra and Elasticsearch conveniently have Debian packages that deploy the daemon scripts out of the box, however there is nothing for Rexster. Has anyone made a script that allows Rexster to run as a daemon?

Looking at the rexster.sh script in titan download zip ../$titan_base/bin/ it calls java to start Rexster up, so I'm thinking that some kind of wrapper like [JSVC](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html) could be used to start it up, unless there is an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

A simple, generic tool to handle this is [Daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/). More details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192056/326516).

If your Debian is new enough to be using Systemd, look into creating a [service script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd). The key commands for using your script would be:

```
systemctl start rexster.service
systemctl enable rexster.service
```

Comment: I played with daemonize and it does run rexster as a daemon, however there's no commands to start or stop the daemon. I'm really looking for it to automatically start itself when the vm starts up.I did play around with systemd, but in my Debian wheezy I managed to destroy my cassandra and elesticsearch daemons from being starting up to start up now. So I think I'm going to stay away

Comment: I also tried the JSVC option but rexster's starting java class doesn't have the init method required so that's no good.

I'm pretty much back to square one now, manually starting the rexster process by hand. I would really love to know how other people using rexster in production have got around this.